# How to pass "%" as part of a parameter to a SqlCommand?

Tags: vb.net, parameter-passing, sqlcommand

When using `SqlDataSource` it is made this way:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT field,field FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE @name"
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear()
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add( _
            New Parameter("name", DbType.String, "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"))
```

But if I try:

```
command.Parameters.Add( _
    New Parameter("name", SqlDbType.VarChar, "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"))
```

or

```
command.Parameters.Add(New Parameter("name", DbType.String, "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"))
```

it fails. How to do it with `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding parameters another way

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & TextBox1.Text & "%"
```

*Additionally just to not cause any issues try using **&** instead of **+**. Not that i can be certain that % is considered a number or arrhythmic condition but it seems to be explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670247/concat-strings-by-and-in-vb-net), well.*

Comment: I also prefer that overload `.Add()`, but for this issue it isn't really any different than what already doesn't work for him.

Comment: Yes it is , especially in the operators, also this is tested and works on my end.

Answer (score 3):

Try structuring your sql statement like this:

```
SELECT field,field FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE N'%' + @name + N'%'
```

Resulting in VB that looks like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT field,field FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE N'%' + @name + N'%'"
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear()
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: I'm really curious why `N'%'` instead of just `'%'` ?

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle I'm assuming the `name` column is an NVarChar type instead of just a Varchar (If it's not, it probably should be). If you don't have the `N`, the type of the resulting string literal is a varchar, and Sql Server would have to do extra work to convert it to NVarchar when it combines it with the rest of the string. In the worst case, missing the `N` can cause a type mismatch that prevents sql server from using an index, resulting in a _significant_ drop in performance. In this case, the initial wildcard already breaks the index, so any difference is likely to be small.