# How to rename data using Linq based on the location of elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

If I have an `Effect` collection that's `IEnumerable<Effect>,` how do I set their .Name property based on their location in the collection?

So in the end, I just want them to be renamed starting from 1 to n.

```
<inside the collection>
effectInstance1.Name = Effect 1;
effectInstance2.Name = Effect 2;
effectInstance3.Name = Effect 3;
...
```

Is this possible with Linq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ isn't really intended for mutation *anyway*; however, you could use something like the `Select` overload that includes the index. But to be honest? Just loop and keep a counter. Much easier to understand, and *that matters*.

```
int position = 0;
foreach(var obj in collection) {
    position++;
    obj.Name = "Effect " + position.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You really want to use string concatenation in a loop? You probably know better than I do; when do you "break even" using String.Format and StringBuilder over simple concatenation?

Comment: @KeithS: what would you do with a StringBuilder?

Comment: @KeithS using StringBuilder is meaningful if you do concat of single `string` variable like `string s = ""; foreach (...) s += x;`. here just two strings are concated on every iteration. `StringBuiler`'s overhead will be bigger.

Comment: The question was about solving with LINQ, why we shoud propose other solutions?

Comment: @KeithS : I have to echo everything Andrey said; StringBuilder *per iteration* would be silly here, compared to a single call to `Concat` per item.

Comment: @Restuta - consider the question: "how do I put a screw in with a hammer?" now... is the correct answer "hit them harder", or is it "use nails, or use a screwdriver" ?

Comment: I belive it is "hit them harder like this, *but* it is better to use screwdriver".

Comment: @Marc, Audrey - I wasn't implying that StringBuilder should be used in this particular case. I probably should have left it at String.Format, which my own answer utilizes. So, to restate; why did you use string concatenation when best practices generally discourage that in favor of String.Format()?

Comment: @KeithS I strongly disagree that string.Format would be a best practice here *at all*. Given the problem statement, vanilla concatenation is a valid and sensible option.

Comment: @KeithS: at this level, the only question should be about readability. string.Format is actually slower than concatenation in this example anyways, since it uses an internal stringbuilder. Anyhoo, there's an entire question devoted to this topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation

Comment: @Jimmy @KeithS actually I'd argue more from the ange of "what is it doing to help us?" - in both cases, as presented, to change the text we have to edit the code. So until we need a resource-based i18n engine, and considerig that were just concatenating two basic values, let's stick with "simple"... IMO. As a minor note is also avoids some string parsing, some boxing, and a virt-call vs static-call, but those are all very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 0;
collection.ForEach(x=>x.Name = "Effect {0}".FormatWith(++n));
```

These are simple extension methods I bodged up back in 3.5:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> lambda)
{
    foreach(var element in collection)
        lambda(element);
}

public static string FormatWith(this string base, params object[] args)
{
    return String.Format(base, args);
}
```

Comment: I kind of wish this was the default method of formatting strings (a la Python's `string.format`) but I can't see the value of hiding a foreach statement inside a (side-effecting!) ForEach extension method. but it smells very Ruby-like, so I guess there must be people who like that style.

Comment: It is indeed a stylistic preference, and I never said it was side-effect free. I find it to be easier to stick this on the end of a Linq chain or collection when the repetitive action is simple. Best case, it's a method I can express as a delegate reference: `collection.ForEach(collection2.Add);`

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best thing to solve with LINQ, but **is** possible:

```
class Program
{
    private class Effect
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Effect> list = new List<Effect> {new Effect(), new Effect(), new Effect()};

        var newElements = list.Select((element, index) =>
        {
            element.Name = "Effect " + index.ToString();
            return element;
        });


        foreach (var effect in newElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(effect.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

Effect 0

Effect 1

Effect 2

Comment: why not to use `ForEach` then? why create **new** list just to modify previous one. this is definitely abuse of linq

Comment: How do you want to use foreach with linq?

Comment: @Restuta if problem can't be solved beautifully and efficiently with Linq it means that you just shouldn't use Linq.

Comment: It doesn't means that you shouldn't answer on the source question that was "how to solve this using linq" Nobody asked for your thoughts about other solutions. In general I agree.

Comment: List<T>.ForEach isn't a linq method, btw.

Comment: @Restuta - your comment above again ties into my hammer analogy.

Comment: And it ties to my "use hammer, *but*" analogy =)