# Displaying text syntax, two different methods, which is better and why?

Tags: c#

What is the advantages between the  syntax in C# (or other programmign languages) to displaying text in an application.

```
decimal fooTotal = 2.53;
```

For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Filtered total: {0:c}", fooTotal);
```

VS

```
Console.WriteLine("Filtered total: " + fooTotal);
```

I see the first method in more examples and books (Current the MVC 3 book I'm going through) but I was taught method 2. I could hypothesize that method one would allow you to change values quickly? The first value would also be displayed in currency which I"m also assuming is more succinct ?

Comment: I felt it's a matter of taste... You can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form applies the [`c` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to the value, which treats it as a currency. To change the second snippet to behave similarly, you could use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Filtered total: " + fooTotal.ToString("c"));
```

I'll often use string concatenation (the second form) for just a single parameter, but when I've got multiple values to include or I want to specify a format specifier, I'll use `string.Format` or the equivalent. (`Console.WriteLine` effectively calls `string.Format` for you here.)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the `string.Format()` / first shown alternative almost always. Biggest advantage is that it allows you to separate *how* you want to print an argument - the text presentation - from the data, the argument itself. The more variables you have to print the cleaner this looks (to me) compared to the string concatenation alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format()` is also better in localization scenarios, where you take the string out of `StringTable`, and the parameters (which you don't know where and in what order they'll appear in the string) from your code.