# What's the differences between "{0}" and "&" in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, concatenation

Please be easy on me guys as I'm still learning.

The following code:

```
Imports System.Console

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim name As String

        num = 1
        name = "John"

        WriteLine("Hello, {0}", num)
        WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name)
        WriteLine("Hello, {0}", 1)
        WriteLine("Hello, {0}", "John")
        WriteLine("5 + 5 = {0}", 5 + 5)

        WriteLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

has the same output as this code:

```
Imports System.Console

    Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim num As Integer
            Dim name As String

            num = 1
            name = "John"

            WriteLine("Hello, " & num)
            WriteLine("Hello, " & name)
            WriteLine("Hello, " & 1)
            WriteLine("Hello, " & "John")
            WriteLine("5 + 5 = " & 5 + 5)

            WriteLine()
        End Sub

    End Module
```

Both output:

> Hello, 1
>   Hello, John
>   Hello, 1
>   Hello, John
>   5 + 5 = 10

I looked everywhere and couldn't find the answer.
When to use *"{0}, {1}, ... etc"*? and when to use *"&"*?
Which is better? And why?

Comment: concatenating two strings, vs variable replacement in a string at any given point.

Comment: [This post][1] has some good answers too (in a C# context).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing here are two very different expressions that just so happen to evaluate to the same output.

The `&` operator in VB.Net is the string concatenation operator.  It essentially works by converting both the left and right side of the expression to a `String` and them adding them together.  This means all the below operations are *roughly* equivalent

```
"Hello " & num
"Hello " & num.ToString()
"Hello " & CStr(num)
```

The `{0}` is a feature of the .Net APIs.  It represents a position within a string which will later be replaced with a value.  The `{0}` refers to the first value passed to the function, `{1}` the second and so on.  This means that all the below operations are *roughly* equivalent

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", num)
Console.WriteLine("Hello " & num & "!")
```

The reason you see the same output is because putting `{0}` at the end of the string is almost exactly the same as a string concatenation of the 2 values.

Answer (score 6):

With `{0}` you're specifying a format placeholder, whereas with `&` you're just concatenating the string.

**Using format placeholders**

```
Dim name As String = String.Format("{0} {1}", "James", "Johnson")
```

**Using string concatenation**

```
Dim name As String = "James" & " " & "Johnson"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `{N}` is called [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx). One advantage, besides readability, is the fact that you can easily set alignment and format properties. Example from the MSDN link:

```
Dim MyInt As Integer = 100
Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", MyInt)
' The example displays the following output
' if en-US is the current culture:
'        $100.00
```

Answer (score 2):

{0} is a placeholder that is used in conjunction with [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) in order to have a more readable and performant string substitutions. Several method calls, including WriteLine, have implicit calls to String.Format.

The problem with using concatenation is that each concat operation will create a new string, which consumes memory.

If you are performing a lot of substitutions, then the best performance will be to use [System.Text.StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead.