# Is there a difference between concatenation and place holding in C# output or is it a matter of preference?

Tags: c#, concatenation, string-concatenation, console.writeline

Just started working with C# for the first time, and while looking through the tutorial, I found nothing on the difference between the Concatenation (`console.writeline("Hello" + user)` where user is a string variable) and the place holder (`console.writeline("Hello {0}" , user`) where user is a string variable) methods for output. Is there a difference or is it simply which way you find easier

Comment: `{0}` uses for formatting, also you may want to look at `Operator Overloading` for example `string strHold += strHold + some string`

Comment: Consider String.Format() for the latter way of using it.

Comment: Format strings are easier to read and modify, in my opinion. I hate looking at concatenated strings that have more quotation marks and plus signs than actual characters.

Answer (score 2):

Its not really specific to C#, lots of languages support both styles. The latter form is usually thought of as 'safer', but I can't quote any specific reason why. It is useful if the item needs to appear in more than 1 place, or if you want to save the format string as a constant. Take a look at this thread for more info: [When is it better to use String.Format vs string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

Using string formatters, as opposed to string concatenation, is almost entirely about readability.  What they actually *do*, and even how they perform, is close enough to the same.

For such a simple case both look all right, but when you have a complex string with lots of values mixed in format strings can end up looking a lot nicer:

Here's a better example:

```
string output = "Hello " + username + ".  I have spent " + executionTime + " seconds trying to figure out that the answer to life is: " + output;
```

vs

```
string output = string.Format("Hello {0}.  I have spent {1} seconds trying to figure out that the answer to life is: {2}"
    , username, executionTime, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matt said Place holding is considered as the safer approach then the simple concatenation, but I am not sure for that reasons(I need to explore on it). But yes one thing is sure that Place Holding is a bit costly operation then Concatenation in terms of Performance. Check this [Blog entry "Formatting Strings"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/formatting-strings.asp) by  Jon Skeet.

Although performance will be effected significantly only if you are using Place Holders for like thousands times or so.