# How could I create a string with an object value in it?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

This questions really isn't hard to understand. I have always wondered this and wondered if possible, how could it be done. Well this is sort what I'd like to do if possible:

```
    int number = 50;
    string text = "The number is %number";
```

Where I wrote ***%number*** in the `string` above, I would like the value of `number` to be inserted into the `string`, because the way I would usually go about doing something like this would be like:

```
    int number = 50;
    string text = "The number is " + number.ToString();
```

Which yes, the way I integrated `number` into the `string` above is an okay way of doing so, but I have always wondered, is it possible to do something such as the first example I wrote, where to put a value of an `object` into a `string` all you would have to do is write some type of `character` or `string` (used to reference the `object`), along with the name of the `object` into a `string` to get a result of a `string` with the value of the `object` in it? Or is there anything sort of like this you're able to do?

Comment: Just a note, most (all?) cases when you're performing simple string concatenation you can simply just add them without explicitly calling `ToString()` or using `String.Format`. For example: `string text = "The number is " + number;` is sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair To come up with an example where it will not work, what about: `string text = currency + amount + " was successfully transferred.";` where neither `currency` nor `amount` is of compile-time type `string`. Then the compiler will complain that the operator `+` cannot be applied to types `MyNamespace.Currency` and `decimal` (for example). An ugly fix might be `string text = currency + (amount + " was successfully transferred.");`. This is not a realistic example, probably.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good thinking. I had not considered combining two non-strings together in that order. If the string literal portion happened to come first (`string text = "Transfer success: " + currency + amount;`) it would work fine. Guess it goes to show how rare such occurrences are (or more likely, they're mundane enough to resolve that I can't really recall them)

Answer (score 5):

You would use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
string text = string.Format("The number is {0}", number);
```

Note that all objects have a `ToString` method, which means that all objects can be used as arguments to `string.Format`, however the default response from `ToString` is to return the full name of the type, which might not make much sense.

For instance, this:

```
public class Dummy
{
}

var d = new Dummy();
string text = string.Format("The dummy is {0}", d);
```

will assign something like the following value to `text`:

```
"The dummy is Your.Namespace.Dummy";
```

You have two options:

1. Override [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) and return something meaningful for your new type
2. Read off a property or something instead, e.g.:

   ```
   string text = string.Format("The dummy is {0}", d.SomeProperty);
   ```

Also note that `string.Format` can take multiple arguments:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = a + b;
string text = string.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, c);
```

There's a lot more to `string.Format` than what I have shown here, so click the link to the documentation (first line of this answer) to learn more.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really do appreciate your answer and everyone else's. You were very quick to respond and I really appreciate it. The `string.Format` will definitely come in handy. I just wish there was a much faster way of writing it, I'm not trying to be lazy, I'd just rather save time writing code. Well thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

*You probably need to check* [`Sting.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

```
string text = String.Format("The number1 is {0},number2 is {1}", number1, number2);
```

It is also worth to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation) discussion regarding ***When is it better to use String.Format vs string concatenation***?
`