# Concatenate variable number of strings

Tags: c#, sql, string, concatenation

This is my query:

```
"select cli.FANTASIA, dbsmp.VEICULO_PLACA, dbsmp.DTINICIOPREV, dbsmp.DTFIMPREV," +
                                                    " dbsmp.DTINICIOREAL, dbsmp.DTFIMREAL,dbsmp.CIDADE_DES,dbsmp.CIDADE_ORI, work.STATUS," +
                                                    " dbsmp.REF1 FROM dbsmp_work work inner join dbsmp "+ 
                                                    " on work.ID_SMP = dbsmp.ID_SMP inner join dbcliente cli "+
                                                    " on dbsmp.ID_CLIENTE = cli.ID_CLIENTE inner join dbSMP_MOTORISTA mot "+
                                                    " on dbsmp.ID_SMP = mot.ID_SMP where dbsmp.ID_CLIENTE = @IDCLIENTE "+
                                                    " and work.STATUS in('F') and work.tipo in ({0})";
```

In `{0}` point, I want to insert a list of strings separated by `,`.

is there a way to pass this list using some method, or something like that, or i'll have to create another string manually, eg. looping in a list?

Comment: How about [using parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)?

Comment: Parameterized Queries, let me search about it

Comment: [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Independet from your question you should use StringBuilder or string.Format instead of "+".

Comment: @Sebi - While that's generally true, in this example, there is no concatenation happening.  The compiler will emit only a single string.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: ...and it's also not _generally true_. Even [Jon Skeet prefers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/296985/284240) `+` for few, simple concatenations ;)

Comment: Thanks i never think about this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
string.Format(sql, "'" + string.Join("', '", arrOfStrings) + "'")
```

Comment: I would have done, `string.Join(",", arrOfStrings.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"))` , but either way it works.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko if arrOfStrings is an empty array, the query turns into invalid.

Comment: True but it really shouldn't be getting to that point if it is empty.

Comment: Thanks @kpull1 and Ash Burlaczenko, i've made a join using your answers and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

```
var resultQuery = string.Format(query, 
                  string.Join(",", stringList.Select(x => 
                                     string.Format("'{0}'", x))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, .NET DB libraries do not let you bind a single parameter to SQL's `IN` list.

If the strings that you bind to the `IN` list always come from inside your program and never from the user input, you can build the list directly, like this:

```
string query = String.Format(
    @"... AND work.tipo in (null, {0})"
,   string.Join(", ", tipiDiLavoro.Select(t => string.Format("'{0}'", t)))
);
```

This would produce a string that looks like this:

```
AND work.tipo in (null, 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

However, if the strings `'a', 'b', 'c'` come from the user, you need to parameterize your query to avoid SQL injection attacks, like this:

```
string query = String.Format(
    @"... AND work.tipo in (null, {0})"
,   string.Join(", ", tipiDiLavoro.Select((t,i) => string.Format("@param{0}", i)))
);
```

for the query that looks like this:

```
AND work.tipo in (null, @param0, @param1, @param2)
```

and bind the `IN` list parameters individually in a separate loop:

```
int pos = 0;
foreach (var code in tipiDiLavoro) {
    cmd.SetParamValue("@param"+pos, code);
    pos++;
}
```

Note the use of `NULL` in the queries. They will never match anything, even in case `work.tipo` contains some `NULL`s. However, adding a `NULL` to the list lets you avoid syntax errors when the list of work types is empty: a query like this is valid, and it does not return anything:

```
... AND work.tipo IN (NULL) -- expanded from an empty list
```

This query, on the other hand, would trigger a syntax error:

```
... AND work.tipo IN ()
```