# Output string with line breaks to file in console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am having problems handling line breaks in the out data for a console application I an working on. The simplfied example below is writing outDataString to out.txt without line breaks. Any thoughts on how to achieve line breaks in out.txt in this case?

```
FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;

string outDataString = "Hi, this is the out data.\nWith a few\n line breaks.";

ostrm = new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);                
writer = new StreamWriter(outDataString);

Console.SetOut(writer);
Console.write(outDataString);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: The example is not complete. It is just to display my question.

Comment: Use Console.WriteLine for each line then and you won't have any issues. Even if you want to use a static literal, you can define an array of lines, eg `var lines=new[] {"Line1","Line2","Line3"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string outDataString = string.Format(
"Hi, this is the out data.{0}With a few{0} line breaks.",
Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: No reason to execute a Format operation when you can create a valid string constant. The string literal will be interned while the Format operation will force the repeated creation and disposal of unnecessary objects

Comment: @Panagiotis It's more readable and has no that much performance issue to worry

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In this case, the Format operation is being used to ensure that the code works cross-platform. Although on Windows you want to use \r\n, if you were running on Linux you'd only want \n. Using Environment.NewLine ensures that the correct characters are being used regardless of what platform you're running on.

Comment: Unless you run it into a frequent loop (eg. polling a service or writing multiple lines), while looking at a memory profiler ramping up from a few MBs to tens of MBs. Depends on what you are doing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is premature optimization. Start with what is *most correct*, which is the use of Environment.NewLine, then if (if!) there are performance issues you can look into alternatives.

Comment: @Alireza In this case the application will run in a Windows environment so I will go for the \r\n suggestion. It seems to give least overheads in terms of performance. Your answer is great though, thanks!

Comment: @Henkealg Think about readability. Not only '\r\n' isn't readable, but also it is vulnerable to typo error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos John Skeet says there is nothing to worry about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation

Comment: Totally different question actually, he's talking about two ways of constructing a string, not comparing a static string with a dynamically constructed one. Besides, WriteLine is even simpler

Answer (score 1):

I think the original code should be:

```
var ostrm = new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);                
var writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);

Console.SetOut(writer);

Console.Write(outDataString);
```

In Windows and DOS before it, you need to enter `\r\n` to change the line. Actually, this goes back to CP/M.

You can just write :

```
string outDataString = "Hi, this is the out data.\r\nWith a few\r\n line breaks.";
```

If you don't really want to write a string literal containing multiple lines, it's better to use [StreamWriter.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60scc1f1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write each line separately, eg:

```
Console.WriteLine(firstLine);
Console.WriteLine(secondLine);
```

or even

```
var lines=new[]{"My First Line","My Second Line"};
foreach(var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(secondLine);
```

Comment: Using `System.Environment.Newline` makes newlines portable to other platforms (e.g. Mono on *NIX).

Comment: And forces an unnecessary operation with memory and CPU costs, which is why the use of Environment.NewLine is so limited

Comment: Portability trumps micro-optimizations in my book, but YMMV :)

Comment: There is a thing like micro-portability too. Besides, you can write a platform agnostic newline to the console without actually forcing a format

Answer (score 1):

```
FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;

string outDataString = String.Format("Hi, this is the out data.{0}With a few{0} line breaks.", System.Environment.NewLine);

ostrm = new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);                
writer = new StreamWriter(outDataString);

Console.SetOut(writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

What platform is this running on? On Windows, you need a carriage return AND a newline to represent a line break, so you need to replace \n with \r\n

Ideally, rather than embedding newlines in literals in this fashion, you should use Environment.NewLine instead, which would make your code more likely to work cross-platform.