# why do I have a syntax error when using concatenation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

trying o use concatenation programming...
instead of saying

```
UpdatePLOF.FolderPath = "PLOF" + plof.Id + ".txt";
```

trying something like:

```
UpdatePLOF.FolderPath = "PLOF {0} .txt", plof.Id;
```

for PLOF {0} .txt is telling me only assignment, call, increment etc...
for plof.id it is telling me ; is needed

Comment: How is it supposed to interpret that comma?

Comment: What is wrong with `"PLOF" + plof.Id + ".txt";` ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `String.Format`

```
UpdatePLOF.FolderPath = string.Format("PLOF {0} .txt", plof.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to concatenate strings in C# and .NET.

`String.Format` is nice for when you'd like to be able to see what the resultant string will look like. However, it is significantly slower than the `+` operator, which the compiler can convert to `String.Concat`. `String.Format` has the extra overhead of having to parse the format string. In your case, it's probably a micro-optimization, but it's something to be aware of.