# Printing variables to console

Tags: c#

Can someone explain difference in this 2 codes.

```
Console.WriteLine("Our total"+ total);
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine("Our total {0}", total);
```

Which of code is more or less correctly than other?

Comment: Latter should be `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Our total {0}", total));`

Comment: both ways are correct

Comment: @Irshad, not true, both work just fine

Comment: with the first one you can just concatenate string (by the way, you are missing a space after "Our Total". The second is much more flexible, allowing you to put the second string in whatever position of the result(e.g `("Our Total is {0} $, you are a good customer", total)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both variants are correct, and in this case practically equivalent.
One uses string concatenation, where you take all the strings needed, and just `+` them together.

The other uses formatting, where you specify the format of the output, and provide parameters that will be replaced by the formatter.

If you have only one parameter, and you only use it once, both approaches are more or less understandable, and have, more or less, similar code lengths.

But, let's say you need to write something more specific, like a person's information in a specified format, e.g.

> FirstName LastName (Age) from City, living on 'Street' #StreetNumber

using concatenation (and assuming that you have a `person` variable) it would look like:

```
string info = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName + " (" 
            + person.Age + ") from " + person.City + ", living on '"
            + person.Street + "' #" + person.StreetNumber;
```

and using formatting, it would look like:

```
string info = string.Format("{0} {1} ({2}) from {3}, living on '{4}' #{5}",
              person.FirstName,  person.LastName, person.Age,
              person.City, person.Street, person.StreetNumber);
```

In the first example, the end format is really non-obvious, and it's hard to say if you've forgotten a quote or a parenthesis somewhere, and in the second case the format is relatively obvious. If you need to change the format later, i.e. if the street name/number need to go before the city, in the first case, you'd need to do some heavy editing, and in the second case, you'd just need to change the format.

---

C# 6.0 has string interpolation, that makes it even easier and more obvious to format strings nicely. You could just write:

```
string info = $"{person.FirstName} {person.LastName} ({person.Age}) from {person.City}, living on '{person.Street}' #{person.StreetNumber}";
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line

```
Console.WriteLine("Our total"+ total);
```

will always contact after left side of `+` sign is finish.

In this line

```
Console.WriteLine("Our total {0}", total);
```

will print where it's position is putted.

Like

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} is our total ", total);
```

This'll print first in the string.

if total is 10

Output :

> 10 is our total.

Both  is correct but with different way of printing.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine("Our total"+ total)` is a direct print of your output.

`Console.WriteLine("Our total {0}", total)` would be like `string.Format("Our total {0}", total)`.

Both are correct but the second is prefered because it ensures proper formatting and is cleaner to read/better to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

A really thorough answer is available [on already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation#296985). In short:

> I suspect other answers may talk about the performance hit, but to be
>   honest it'll be minimal if present at all - and this concatenation
>   version doesn't need to parse the format string.

Essentially it is up to the writer as to what he thinks is more readable.