# Why would I use string interpolation in c#, since it's performes not as good as adding strings or variables?

Tags: c#, string, interpolation, string-interpolation

So yesterday I saw this tutorial on c# and I learned about string interpolation. I've always programmed in java and just used the + to add strings.
Now I'm trying to find out why you would use interpolation over just adding these strings.
For example:

```
int number = 203;
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Temp/" + number);
```

I feel like this works perfectly and no reason why I should use interpolation.
Interpolation for example:

```
int number;
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Temp/{0}", number);
```

When I googled it, I found a performance test.
In this test they found that interpolating is slower than adding both 2 variables to a string.

Could anyone please explain to me why or when I should use interpolation over adding, since interpolation performes worse?

Comment: I thinks it is just simplier. Especially when you have more variables. In c# 6.0 you can also use: `$"C:/Temp/{number}"`;

Comment: Your example of 'string interpolation' is totally wrong

Comment: Note that string interpolation in C# 6 (there is no string interpolation before that) internally uses `string.Format`, so you are essentially asking why one would use `string.Format` over concatenating manually.

Comment: Alright, I get why it might be easier if you are used to it. But what about the performance, wouldn't it be worth to just go for the optimized method?

Comment: [When is it better to use String.Format vs string concatenation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/296978/216074)

Comment: @poke Thank you, I hadn't seen the part about the performance.