# What is the difference between String.Format and Composite String in C#?

Tags: c#, string.format

What is the difference between those two syntaxes?

Is there any situation where one must use String.Format rather than composite string?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:d} {0:t}",DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:d} {0:t}",DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: You don't have to use `string.Format` at all. Just use interpolated string `$"{DateTime.Now}"`. `Console.WriteLine` uses `String.Format` under the hood, so these two lines are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it better to use String.Format vs string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any difference between them because

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:d} {0:t}",DateTime.Now);
```

that will call `String.Format` function by this overload function.

```
public virtual void WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
{
    WriteLine(String.Format(FormatProvider, format, arg0));
}
```

[console.WriteLine](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=console.writeline) Source code

Comment: More specifically, it calls [`TextWriter.Write`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,352) which then calls `String.Format`

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed a situation where String.Format or interpolated string has to be used rather than normal composite string.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("......");
SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT userAddress FROM tblUserData WHERE userName = '" + userName + "'", myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT userAddress FROM tblUserData WHERE userName = '{0}'", userName, myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter3 = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT userAddress FROM tblUserData WHERE userName = '{0}'", userName), myConnection);
SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter4 = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT userAddress FROM tblUserData WHERE userName = '{userName}'",myConnection);
```

myDataAdapter2 is not working because of the incorrect parameters.

(Yeah, normally, SELECT statement is assigned to a string variable.)