# How to Insert Line Breaks When Emailing?

Tags: asp.net, email, blogengine.net, blog-engine

Neither the "\n" or "<br />" are working. I'm trying to insert line breaks when emailing the contents of a custom form:

```
protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
        mailBody.Append("Company Name: " + companyText.Text.Trim() + "\n\n");
        mailBody.Append("Name: " + firstNameText.Text.Trim() + " " 
            + lastNameText.Text.Trim() + "\n\n");
        mailBody.Append("Email: " + emailText.Text.Trim() + "\n\n");

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tradeText.Text))
            mailBody.Append("Trade: " + tradeText.Text.Trim() + "\n\n");

            bool success = SendEmail(emailText.Text.Trim(), 
                companyText.Text.Trim(), "SubContractors Form Submission",
                    mailBody.ToString()); 
    }
}

private bool SendEmail(string email, string name, 
    string subject, string message)
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(BlogSettings.Instance.Email, name);
        mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(email, name);

        mail.To.Add(BlogSettings.Instance.Email);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body += message;

        if (Utils.SendMailMessage(mail).Length > 0)
        {
            return false;
        };
    }
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I got <br /> working eventually. Reason it didn't work was because this was the original code I got from the Contact form:

```
mail.Body += message.Replace("\n\n", "<br />");
```

`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml` is set to true in the core library code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- the [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) operator when using the default [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = False](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) mode;
- implement a line-break via the "br" tag when the [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) mode is **True**.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Environment.NewLine`.

```
mailBody.Append("Email: " + emailText.Text.Trim() + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `AppendLine` rather than `Append` should work for what you're doing:

```
StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();

string company = companyText.Text.Trim();
string firstName = firstNameText.Text.Trim();
string lastName = lastNameText.Text.Trim();
string email = emailText.Text.Trim();
string trade = tradeText.Text.Trim();

mailBody.AppendFormat("Company Name: {0}", company).AppendLine();
mailBody.AppendFormat("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName).AppendLine();
mailBody.AppendFormat("Email: {0}", email).AppendLine();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(trade))
{
    mailBody.AppendFormat("Trade: {0}", trade).AppendLine();
}

bool success = SendEmail(email, company, "SubContractors Form Submission", 
    mailBody.ToString());
```

---

Added `AppendFormat()` for clarity

---

created variables to eliminate multiple `.Trim()`ing of the same text in a few cases

---

Adapted `AppendFormat().AppendLine()` as described here for performace: [When do you use StringBuilder.AppendLine/string.Format vs. StringBuilder.AppendFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349724/when-do-you-use-stringbuilder-appendline-string-format-vs-stringbuilder-appendf)

Comment: Very informative answer. I got the <br /> working eventually... am updating question for clarification. Thanks :-)