# Why use String.Format?

Tags: c#, string, vb.net, string.format

Why would anyone use `String.Format` in C# and VB .NET as opposed to the concatenation operators (`&` in VB, and `+` in C#)?

What is the main difference? Why are everyone so interested in using `String.Format`? I am very curious.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/c-string-output-format-or-concat

Comment: Because the one who thought + operator is evil and always use `string.Format` is wrong.

Comment: See also my accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019508/c-string-formatting/3019525#3019525

Answer (score 411, accepted):

I can see a number of reasons:

**Readability**

```
string s = string.Format("Hey, {0} it is the {1}st day of {2}.  I feel {3}!", _name, _day, _month, _feeling);
```

vs:

```
string s = "Hey," + _name + " it is the " + _day + "st day of " + _month + ".  I feel " + feeling + "!";
```

**Format Specifiers**
(and this includes the fact you can write custom formatters)

```
string s = string.Format("Invoice number: {0:0000}", _invoiceNum);
```

vs:

```
string s = "Invoice Number = " + ("0000" + _invoiceNum).Substr(..... /*can't even be bothered to type it*/)
```

**String Template Persistence**

What if I want to store string templates in the database?  With string formatting:

```
_id         _translation
  1         Welcome {0} to {1}.  Today is {2}.
  2         You have {0} products in your basket.
  3         Thank-you for your order.  Your {0} will arrive in {1} working days.
```

vs:

```
_id         _translation
  1         Welcome
  2         to
  3         .  Today is
  4         . 
  5         You have
  6         products in your basket.
  7         Someone
  8         just shoot
  9         the developer.
```

Comment: I agree on both but I think that the main reason is that you can read the string without the noise of the variable names inside.

Comment: I don't think the separation of concerns provided by removing string templates from your code should be under-estimated. If some bad wording becomes an issue, this can mean the difference between a simple config change or database update, and a full blown emergency change.

Comment: +1 for the  `Someone           just shoot         the developer.` ;-)

Comment: For your 'substr' example you should actually use _invoiceNum.ToString("00000").  ToString supports the same composite formatting settings as string.Format()  When you have just a single value to be formatted ToString() is often simpler/clearer than Format().

Comment: @Ash, absolutely correct.  I used the elongated awful format as I sort of assumed that someone who might use concatenation everywhere might also choose the hard way and shun formatting completely :)  But, you have a point!

Comment: I don't know about you, but I read the one without formatting better. Especially when I want to know what goes where, I have to go back and forth between the text and the params, and that's not even counting the possibility of miscounting and getting it wrong (that may not be an issue with fewer parameters, but go over 10 and it stops being fun). As Ashley pointed out, the second point is null if you use the formatting built in the ToString method. I agree with the third one, but I don't think I'll ever use it outside of that particular case.

Comment: Your readability example sure looks like a clear win... for the concat approach.  Why would I _want_ to have to scan the precise order of arguments to determine which one goes where?

Comment: +1  - Also using `String.Format` is faster and uses less overhead. Using concat `+`/`&` has to rebuild the string each time which can be very bad in large string objects. The very definition of a `string` is that it should be defined once and reused many times.(Many books teach us to use concat as examples but never tell us about performance!!) Building string should use `StringBuilder` which is even faster than `String.Format` ! VERY GOOD ANSWER- Developers need to learn to write readable code and keep performance in mind too!

Comment: @ppumkin That's not true.  When you have a specific number of  + operators all specified in a single expression it will be converted, by the compiler, into a single call to `string.Concat`, and there will not be any intermediate strings created.  Using a StringBuilder would in fact *hurt* performance, not help it, since Concat can create an internal buffer of exactly the right size from the start.  A SB is used when you have some sort of loop or other control block such that the number of strings being concatted isn't known by the compiler at compile time.

Comment: Well - I went back to the MSDN and read a bit- I thouhg it said somehwere that using `&` or `+` rebuilds the String making it less efficient. [Then i found this practical test](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14936/StringBuilder-vs-String-Fast-String-Operations-wit) Which yields interesting results. The table near the end- the author advises to use `+` for 2 strings but `String.Join` for more than 2! [OK - Jon Skeet also agrees with that in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/585897/706363) - Can you give us a reference to prove your comment.I know you have good rep and all..

Comment: [And this article just says. IT DOESN'T MATTER](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)  :)  Heheh, As long as we don't use the immutable strings in massive loops.

Comment: How to write this using String.Format() Function...  Ex: String.Format(" {0} ","NDD-255252");  How to just display First 3 Chars only using String Formatting... Help me..

Comment: @Drua, post a question?

Comment: I can't believe C# doesn't inherently support named string format parameters, e.g. {"foo"}.

Comment: @wisbucky, would be easy enough to implement.  However, ordinal indexes are far more performant - we're spending enough time with strings, why spend more? :)

Comment: As an additional argument in favor of concat being more legible, your sample code says `"the {1}st day"`, which reads well because it looks like first, but in reality it also says seconst, thirst, fourst, fifst, etc. The error is much easier to see at a glance when the code reads `"the " + _day + "st"`.

Comment: I would also like to mention here that C# now supports string interpolation, which comes with the benefits of string.format, yet offers a shorter syntax and is easier to read, due to the inline evaluation of variables and functions.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation.  I recommend you use that over string.format.

Comment: @DaffyPunk Great option to point out. That's really neat. It'll basically interpret as code whatever you through at it (within reason). Also, the performance testing in your link shows that `string.Format` is slower than `string.Concat`, which stands in agreement with Servy's reply to ppumpkin.

Answer (score 92):

Besides being a bit easier to read and adding a few more operators, it's also beneficial if your application is internationalized.  A lot of times the variables are numbers or key words which will be in a different order for different languages.  By using String.Format, your code can remain unchanged while different strings will go into resource files.  So, the code would end up being

```
String.Format(resource.GetString("MyResourceString"), str1, str2, str3);
```

While your resource strings end up being

English:  `"blah blah {0} blah blah {1} blah {2}"`

Russian:  `"{0} blet blet blet {2} blet {1}"`

Where Russian may have different rules on how things get addressed so the order is different or sentence structure is different.

Comment: +1 I had never considered String.Format's application to localisation until I saw this.

Answer (score 27):

First, I find

```
string s = String.Format(
    "Your order {0} will be delivered on {1:yyyy-MM-dd}. Your total cost is {2:C}.",
    orderNumber,
    orderDeliveryDate,
    orderCost
);
```

far easier to read, write and maintain than

```
string s = "Your order " +
           orderNumber.ToString() +
           " will be delivered on " +
           orderDeliveryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +
           "." +
           "Your total cost is " +
           orderCost.ToString("C") + 
           ".";
```

Look how much more maintainable the following is

```
string s = String.Format(
    "Year = {0:yyyy}, Month = {0:MM}, Day = {0:dd}",
    date
);
```

over the alternative where you'd have to repeat `date` three times.

Second, the format specifiers that `String.Format` provides give you great flexibility over the output of the string in a way that is easier to read, write and maintain than just using plain old concatenation. Additionally, it's easier to get culture concerns right with `String.Format`.

Third, when performance does matter, `String.Format` will outperform concatenation. Behind the scenes it uses a `StringBuilder` and avoids the [Schlemiel the Painter problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm).

Comment: Just a note: There is no Schlemiel the Painter problem with repeated `+`s in a line. They are compiled to a single `string.Concat` call.

Comment: Actually `string.Concat` outperforms `String.Format` (at least for a single short strings). However there are many many factor involved (which can make one more efficient than the other). In situations in which the execution time would matter much (repeating same operation countless times), the speed saved by using `string.Concat` will be negligible though.

Comment: You don't have to call ToString() explicitly. `"Your order " + orderNumber.ToString()` is same as `"Your order " + orderNumber`

Comment: There actually **is** a Schlemiel the Painter problem with `+`s, it's just a bit delayed. `String.Concat` only takes up to four arguments, so the way five or more strings are joined via `+`s is by concatting them in groups of up to four, and then concatting **those** strings, and so on.

Answer (score 17):

Several reasons:

1. `String.Format()` is very powerful. You can use simple format indicators (like fixed width, currency, character lengths, etc) right in the format string. You can even create your own format providers for things like expanding enums, mapping specific inputs to much more complicated outputs, or localization.
2. You can do some powerful things by putting format strings in configuration files.
3. `String.Format()` is often faster, as it uses a `StringBuilder` and an efficient state machine behind the scenes, whereas string concatenation in .Net is relatively slow. For small strings the difference is negligible, but it can be noticable as the size of the string and number of substituted values increases.
4. `String.Format()` is actually more familiar to many programmers, especially those coming from backgrounds that use variants of the old C `printf()` function.

Finally, don't forget `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`.  `String.Format()` actually uses this method behind the scenes*, and going to the `StringBuilder` directly can give you a kind of hybrid approach: explicitly use `.Append()` (analogous to concatenation) for some parts of a large string, and use `.AppendFormat()` in others.

---

<sub>* [edit] Original answer is now 8 years old, and I've since seen an indication this may have changed when string interpolation was added to .Net. However, I haven't gone back to the reference source to verify the change yet.</sub>

Comment: `string.Format` usually won't be faster than a few string concatenations, because the format string also needs to be parsed and copied.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In fact, there is another caveat with `string.Format` as compared to concatenation + `ToString()`: value types are boxed as described here: http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/08/08/Avoid-Boxing-When-Using-StringFormat-with-Value-Types.aspx. Nonetheless, `string.Format` is a very powerful and great tool and performance usually not the most important criteria.

Comment: In reference to #3: String builder is not faster than concatenation.  The myth that it is is supported by "tests" that actually do concatenation on different lines (or in a loop).  When all concatenation is done on a single line, the compiler translates it into a string.append(paramaarray) call, which is the most efficient out of all options.  During a string.append call, the exact size of the destination string is known ahead of time and can be allocated immediately and each character copied only once.

Answer (score 5):

[`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) adds many options in addition to the concatenation operators, including the ability to specify the specific format of each item added into the string.

For details on what is possible, I'd recommend reading the section on MSDN titled [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).  It explains the advantage of `String.Format` (as well as `xxx.WriteLine` and other methods that support composite formatting) over normal concatenation operators.

Comment: String format is nice but slower than concatenation. enough said.

Answer (score 4):

There's interesting stuff on the performance aspects in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c)

However I personally would still recommend `string.Format` unless performance is critical for readability reasons.

```
string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, value);
```

Is more readable than

```
key + ": " + value
```

For instance. Also provides a nice separation of concerns. Means you can have

```
string.Format(GetConfigValue("KeyValueFormat"), key, value);
```

And then changing your key value format from `"{0}: {1}"` to `"{0} - {1}"` becomes a config change rather than a code change.

`string.Format` also has a bunch of format provision built into it, integers, date formatting, etc.

Comment: If you're interested in the performance aspect, you might find this other question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761121/performance-issue-comparing-to-string-format

Answer (score 2):

One reason it is not preferable to write the string like `'string +"Value"+ string'` is because of Localization. In cases where localization is occurring we want the localized string to be correctly formatted, which could be very different from the language being coded in.

For example we need to show the following error in different languages:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format(ErrorManager.GetError("PIDV001").Description, proposalvalue.ProposalSource)
```

where

`'ErrorCollector.GetError("ERR001").ErrorDescription'` returns a string like `"Your ID {0} is not valid"`. This message must be localized in many languages. In that case we can't use + in C#. We need to follow string.format.