# Remove Stop Words From text File

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

i want to remove stop words from my text file and i write the following code for this purpose

```
 TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\output.txt");
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:\\input1.txt");
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                string[] stopWord = new string[] { "is", "are", "am","could","will" };
                foreach (string word in stopWord)
                {
                    line = line.Replace(word, "");
                    tw.Write("+"+line);
                }
                tw.Write("\r\n");
            }
```

but it doesn't show the result in the **output file** and the output file remain empty.

Comment: Check this out:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447980/remove-stop-words-from-text-c-sharp

Comment: Are you closing the output file StreamWriter?

Comment: You really need to phrase your question... in the form of a question.

Answer (score 6):

A regular expression might be perfect for the job:

```
        Regex replacer = new Regex("\b(?:is|are|am|could|will)\b");
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input.txt"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    replacer.Replace(line, "");
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

This method will only replace the words with blanks and do nothing with the stopwords if they are part of another word.

Good luck with your quest.

Answer (score 2):

The following works as expected for me. However, it's not a good approach because it will remove the stop words even when they are part of a larger word. Also, it doesn't clean up extra spaces between removed words.

```
string[] stopWord = new string[] { "is", "are", "am","could","will" };

TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output.txt");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input.txt");

string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (string word in stopWord)
    {
        line = line.Replace(word, "");
    }
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
reader.Close();
writer.Close();
```

Also, I recommend using `using` statements for when you create your streams in order to ensure the files are closed in a timely manner.

Comment: @jonathan: Sir this code is not work properly,, i want to remove stop word from text file

Comment: This is stackoverflow, which is for asking technical questions. The code I posted fixed the errors in your code. To provide additional help to you, I also explained some problems with the approach you are taking. If you have other problems, you might want to post another question. But I strongly recommend you learn to be far more specific than "not working properly", which tells me absolutely nothing about the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your IO objects in using statements so that they are disposed properly.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new TextWrite("D:\\output.txt"))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:\\input1.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
            string[] stopWord = new string[] { "is", "are", "am","could","will" };
            foreach (string word in stopWord)
            {
                line = line.Replace(word, "");
                tw.Write("+"+line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` in `using() {}` clauses.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\output.txt")
{
  ...
}
```

You may also want to call `tw.Flush()` at the very end.