# How do I ignore some word from the paragraph using C# with Asp.net web-form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table call **Reviws** in that table I have column call **Description**
so user can add the description. Now what I need is in that description paragraph need to ignore some words  and display.

I have some words like

`a
is
about
above
after
again
against
all`

This is the sample paragraph.

**Anuradhapura is a major city in Sri Lanka. It is the capital city of North Central Province, Sri Lanka and the capital of Anuradhapura District.**

but I want display some words only like this

**Anuradhapura  major city Sri Lanka.capital city  North Central Province, Sri Lanka capital Anuradhapura District.**

This  this how now I display my description

**Review.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    string constr = "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=ReviewDB;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Description, Place FROM Reviews"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Review.aspx**

```
    <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" PageSize="10">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="500px" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the snippet for removing unwanted words in a string

```
string description = "Anuradhapura is a major city in Sri Lanka. It is the capital city of North Central Province, Sri Lanka and the capital of Anuradhapura District";
List<string> ignoredWords = new List<string>() { "a","is","about","above","after","again","against","all", "just", "text","of","and","it","the" };
description = string.Join(" ", description.Split().Where(words => !ignoredWords.Contains(words, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Anuradhapura major city in Sri Lanka. capital city North Central Province, Sri Lanka capital Anuradhapura District
```

Now, as you requirement I have merged the code to give a complete answer.

Here I have created a sample `DataTable`, whereas you have it from `Database`and I have removed the paging, do add it in your code.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" PageSize="10" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="500px" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
</Columns>
```

Here I have added `OnRowDataBound` event to it.

**CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    string constr = "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=ReviewDB;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Description, Place FROM Reviews"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//In `RowDataBound` I'm doing all the manipulations
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (drv["Description"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                string description = Convert.ToString(drv["Description"]);
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = RemoveUnwanedWords(description);
            }
        } 
    }

    public string RemoveUnwanedWords(string description)
    {
        List<string> ignoredWords = new List<string>() { "a", "is", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "just", "text", "of", "and", "it", "the" };
        return string.Join(" ", description.Split().Where(words => !ignoredWords.Contains(words, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
    }
```

Comment: @Developer Let me see your  `Gridview` control, in the aspx page

Comment: please chek my question @durga

Comment: if you can merge your idea with my code plz and let me know how to pass aspx page also

Comment: @Developer Do see my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: check this you calling `GetData();` so it will return same ` _reviewer["Description"] = "Anuradhapura is a major city in Sri Lanka. It is the capital city of North Central Province, Sri Lanka and the capital of Anuradhapura District";
        _reviewer["Place"] = "Country";` ?????

Comment: @Developer Why are you are worried about the static data,You have a query of `SELECT Description, Place FROM Reviews`. So I have taken  two columns of `Description` and `Place`. I have clearly mentioned that you have to get it from a `database`. You just have to use `this.BindGrid();` in the `!this.IsPostBack` condition of `Page_Load` method

Comment: so between where i want paste to ur code? im little confuse ?

Comment: if i use `this.BindGrid();` it will call my methods right not your any methods sry if im rong ?

Comment: @Developer See I have updated check it and let me know

Comment: Hello whts im wrong or you with your coding chek when i call page_load its calling my function right `this.BindGrid();` thr is no any connection with ur functions right so im getting same out put which i got from my code :)

Comment: can you check please

Comment: Omg sorry mam :) its working

Comment: wheni get 15 ponits only it will automatically go up :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple if your words are separated by space only:

```
var DescWords = Description.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

//WordsToRemove is the list of words that you don't want to show.
var NewDesc = String.Join(" ", DescWords.Except(WordsToRemove));
```

Make sure you add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file. Also note that you need to replace `Description` with the name of the actual `DataTable` value that you want to fix. For example, this could be `dt[0]["Description"]` or something.

If your description contains other punctuations, this will become a bit more involved, but can still be achieved pretty easily.

### Edit

If your string contains multiple delimiters, you can handle it like this:

```
var WordsToRemove = new[] { "a", "is", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all" };

var Delimiters = ".,;: ()!?/";
int LastIndex = 0;
var NewDesc = "";

for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
{
  var Description = dt.Rows[row]["Description"].ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < Description.Length; i++)
{
  if (Delimiters.IndexOf(Description[i]) >= 0)
  {
    var Word = Description.Substring(LastIndex, i - LastIndex + 1);
    if (WordsToRemove.Contains(Word.Trim(Delimiters.ToCharArray())))
      NewDesc += Description[i];
    else
      NewDesc += Word;

    LastIndex = i + 1;
  }
}
}
```

Inject this code below `sda.Fill(dt);` line in your code. In real world, problems like this are solved slightly differently, e.g. you should consider moving this code to a function, plus you should use a `StringBuilder` instead of `string`, but since you're a beginner, I'm just leaving hints for you.

Comment: How to specify those word here? i you can merge your idea with my code plz?

Comment: this is my first C#  program so im really confuse now so tell me where i want use ur code and how insight this function or where ? using `(DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }`

Comment: or update your code with mine please :(

Comment: @Developer: See my edit.

Comment: im getting this error [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoLPyyQ3jAjemgxOU5IdXhPWEE)

Comment: it says `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expersion of Type 'Data Table'`

Comment: @Developer: See my new edit.

Comment: no your code showing error in second for loop bro :(

Comment: @Developer: And the error is?

Comment: [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoLPyyQ3jAjdzFsYnNnWTFsMVE)

Comment: @Developer: Try it now.

Comment: bro [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoLPyyQ3jAjaVk2ekVEbG9XdFk) @dotNET i can try this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447980/remove-stop-words-from-text-c-sharp)but i dont knw how to pass the description `StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder("Did you try this yourself before asking");`

Answer (score 0):

Access the content of `DataTable` as such:

```
string myData=dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Create a loop for the loop for the string to remove the desired words

```
string bannedWords = @"\b(this|is|the|list|of|banned|words)\b";

foreach(data in myData)
    string replaced = Regex.Replace(data, bannedWords, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then plug the string in the `GridView`

Comment: Two things: Regex is a bit of an overkill for this situation. Second and more important, this will leave double spaces everywhere in the sentence.

Comment: @Alfie McNarutoad shall i try your idea? and how to display in a view my first c# program this :(