# What is the difference between {0} and +?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

Is there any difference between the use of `{0}` and `+` as they both are doing the same work of printing the *length* on the screen:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length={0}", length);
Console.WriteLine("Length="   + length);
```

Comment: There is no difference in the end result, but there is certainly a difference in how it is achieved.

Comment: Yes, C# is case sensitive, so we can't tell if Length is different from length.

Comment: But if you want more info, the first line will have Length={0} in the Intern pool, but in the second one Length will be in the Intern pool.

Answer (score 30):

In your trivial example there's no difference. But there are very good reasons to prefer the formatted (`{0}`) option: it makes localization of international software much, much easier, and it makes editing your existing strings by third parties much easier.

Imagine for example you're writing a compiler that produces this error message:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'"
```

Do you really want to write the code

```
Console.WriteLine("Cannot implicitly convert type '" + sourceType + "' to '" + targetType + "'");
```

?   Good heavens no. You want to put this string into a resource:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type '{0}' to '{1}'"
```

and then write

```
Console.WriteLine(FormatError(Resources.NoImplicitConversion, sourceType, targetType));
```

Because then you have the freedom to decide that you want to change that to:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert from an expression of type '{0}' to the type '{1}'"
```

Or

```
"Conversion to '{1}' is not legal with a source expression of type '{0}'"
```

**These choices can be made later, by English majors, without requiring changes to the code.**

You can also translate those resources into other languages, again **without changing the code**.

Start always using formatting strings now; when you need to write localizable software that uses string resources properly, you'll already be in the habit.

Comment: The best argument I've seen for using formatting strings during the 5 years of reading StackOverflow and previously Joel's blog.

Answer (score 2):

The second line will create a string and print the string out.
The first line will use [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/txafckwd.aspx), like string.Format.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671610/why-use-string-format) are some good reasons to use composite formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference.

ex:

```
Console.WriteLine("the length is {0} which is the length", length);
Console.WriteLine("the length is "+length+" which is the length");
```

`+` concatenates two strings, `{0}` is a placeholder for a string to be inserted.

Comment: Is there *really* a difference between the concatenation and the insertion? The only difference I see is convenience.

Comment: I would say *formats* instead of *inserts*, since really it does a `String.Format(...)`.

Comment: @Daniel I think it's worth making a distinction - otherwise some people may get the impression that you can use the `{0}` placeholder syntax *anywhere*. But you can only use it with methods that specifically have code to interpret the string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`{n}` is a placeholder which can be used with multiple options.  *where n is a number*

In your example it would make a difference and the end result would be same that is concatenation of two string. However in something like

```
var firstName = "babba";
var lastName ="abba";
var dataOfBirth = new Date();

Console
   .Write(" Person First Name : {0} | Last Name {1} }| Last Login : {2:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", 
          firstName, 
          secondName, 
          dateOfBirth);
```

it provides a easy to read interface with easy formatting

Answer (score 0):

`{n}` where `n >= 0` allows you to substitute values in order of occurrence in the string.

```
string demo = "demo", example = "example";
Console.WriteLine("This is a {0} string used as an {1}", demo, example);
```

`+` allows you to concatenate two or more strings together.

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a " + demo + " string used as an " + example);
```

Comment: The concatenate will actually end up like this: `string.Concat("This is a ", demo, " string used as an ", example);` after the compiler is done with it.