# Formatting the output of a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I am new to C#. I am studying it in a module in college. We have been given an assignment which involves us having to create a simple booking application using the various components included in the toolbox in Visual Studio.

The UI has a `ListBox` which enables the user to select multiple names of people that will attend the event. The selected items are concatenated to a `String` and output in a `Label` when the user confirms the selection.

This is the code where I get the values from the `ListBox`

```
 protected void btnRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Update the summary label with the details of the booking.
    n = name.Text;
    en = eventName.Text;
    r = room.SelectedItem.ToString();
    d = cal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

    foreach (ListItem li in attendees.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            people += li.Text + " ";
        }
    }


    confirmation.Text = r + " has been booked on " + d + " by " + n + " for " + en + ". " + people + " will be attending.";
}
```

Below is my entire code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Variables
    public TextBox name;
    public TextBox eventName;
    public Label confirmation;
    public DropDownList room;
    public Calendar cal;
    public Button btn;
    public ListBox attendees;

    //Booking variables - store all information relating to booking in these variables
    public String n; //name of person placing booking
    public String en; //name of event
    public String r; //room it will take place
    public List<String> att; //list of people attending
    public String d; //date it will be held on

    public String people;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get references to components
        name = txtName;
        eventName = txtEvent;
        room = droplistRooms;
        attendees = attendeelist;
        cal = Calendar1;
        btn = btnRequest;
        confirmation = lblSummary;

    }
    protected void btnRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Update the summary label with the details of the booking.
        n = name.Text;
        en = eventName.Text;
        r = room.SelectedItem.ToString();
        d = cal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

        foreach (ListItem li in attendees.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                people += li.Text + " ";
            }
        }


        confirmation.Text = r + " has been booked on " + d + " by " + n + " for " + en + ". " + people + " will be attending.";
    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d = cal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

The output is this:

**Room 2 has been booked on 08/10/2013 by Jason Manford for Comedy Gig. Jack Coldrick Bill Gates Larry Page Jimmy Wales will be attending.**

However I would like to add an and to the last name of the person attending the event. How would I go about doing this. Would I have to use a `List`?

Many Thanks...

Comment: Instead of concatenation by `+`, use `string.Format()`

Comment: Besides an "and" you also probably want commas separating the other names. You just need to modify how you are building `people`.

Comment: Ok will do, is there an advantage to using your method?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671610/why-use-string-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try copying the selected items into another collection and using a simple counter:

```
int counter = 1; // start at 1 so that the counter is in line with the number of items that the loop has iterated over (instead of 0 which would be better for indexing into the collection)

List<ListItem> selectedItems = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (ListItem li in attendees.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        selectedItems.Add(li);
    }
}

foreach (ListItem li in selectedItems)
{
    counter++;

    if (selectedItems.Count > 1 && i == selectedItems.Count) // check after the counter has been incremented so that only the last item triggers it
    {
        people += " and";
    }

    people += li.Text + " ";
}
```

As pointed out by a few people, you should also think about using a `StringBuilder`, as strings are immutable in .Net, which means that they cannot be modified. Every time you append text to a string, behind the scenes a new string is being created with the new contents and the old one is being discarded. As you can imagine, if you have a lot of names in the list, this could eventually end up impacting performance. Example below:

```
List<ListItem> selectedItems = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (ListItem li in attendees.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        selectedItems.Add(li);
    }
}

StringBuilder sbPeople = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 1; // start at 1 so that the counter is in line with the number of items that the loop has iterated over (instead of 0 which would be better for indexing into the collection)

foreach (ListItem li in attendees.SelectedItems)
{
    counter++;

    if (selectedItems.Count > 1 && i == selectedItems.Count) // check after the counter has been incremented so that only the last item triggers it
    {
        sbPeople.Append(" and");
    }

    sbPeople.Append(li.Text);
    sbPeople.Append(" ");
}
```

Reference to the `StringBuilder` docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: You might want to account for the case where the list contains a single name.

Comment: And suggest using a `StringBuilder` :)

Comment: @Khan KHAAAAAAN!! *ahem* will do!

Comment: Your counting scheme works, but it's not the norm.  I had to look at it a few times to convince myself your `i == attendees.Count` wasn't a bug.   If you start at 1, generally you don't increment the counter until the end of each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @TonyVitabile No it's not the norm, I did think of starting at 0 and then checking it like `i < attendees.Count` but I thought that might have been more confusing considering the OP is a student and perhaps not that experienced with C#. It can easily be modified if they find it less confusing that way though =]

Comment: @Sean OP is using ASP .NET, there is no `SelectedItems` property in `ListBox`!

Comment: @Sean: Given that they are a student, it seems to me that it would serve them better to see how loops like that are normally constructed.  They're going to run into the "start counting at 0 and stop at `MyCollection.Count - 1` loop in all of the code they see in the real world, aren't they?

Comment: @TonyVitabile I hadn't thought of it that way.. I did put a comment in to explain what I had done though, if that helps.. =]

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM There is no `ListBox` in ASP.Net ;P and it doesn't say anywhere in the question that they are using ASP.Net

Comment: @Sean sorry I left out the fact that I was using ASP.Net. Apologies. Your answer is very good but I am running into a problem when I try to use the `SelectedItems` property.

Comment: @Sean `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page` and [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx)

Comment: @Sean are you use `counter` or `i`?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Oh yes. And there is a `ListBox`. My bad. I shall change the code then.

Comment: @EvilGeniusJamie Thanks, changed `i` to `counter`.

Comment: @Javacadabra, this could be expressed much more direct using linq, see my answer. The looping part is just to verbose if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

```
var p = new List<string>() {"person1", "person2", "person3"};
string people;
if(p.Count == 1)
    people = p[0];
else
    people = string.Join(", ", p.Take(p.Count - 1)) + " and " + p[p.Count - 1]
```

To better fit your code I would write something like this (as indirectly suggested from the comments):

```
var p = attendees.Items.OfType<ListItem>.Where(y => y.Selected).Select(y => y.Text).ToList();
var people = "";
if(p.Count == 1)
    people = p[0];
if(p.Count > 1)
    people = string.Join(", ", p.Take(p.Count - 1)) + " and " + p[p.Count - 1]

Confirmation.Text = string.Format("{0} has been booked on {1} by {2} for {3}. {4} will be attending", r, d, n, en, people);
```

Comment: and `var p = attendees.Items.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();` - also, `if (p.Count < 1) { people = string.empty; }`

Comment: @Corak `var p = list.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(c => c.Selected).Select(c => c.Text).ToList();`

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM - Yes, thank you. And thank everyone involved in introducing generics to .Net so I usually don't have to specify the desired type like that when working with lists/collections/whatever. ^_^;

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your foreach with this one

```
var peopleList = new List<string>();

foreach (ListItem li in attendees.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
       peopleList.Add(li.Text);
}

var people = string.Join(",", list.Take(list.Count - 1));
people += list.Count > 1 ? " and " + list.Last() : list.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the answer in line with your question, I'll make this easy to follow - although I'm use StringBuilder instead of appending a string - I've seen this method process larger strings much faster.

```
var selectedPeople = new List<string>();

foreach (ListItem li in attendees.Items)
{

    if (li.Selected)
    {
        people.Add(li.Text);
    }

}
var sb = new StringBuilder();
if (selectedPeople.Count == 0)
{
    sb.Append("");
}
else
{
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedPeople.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
            if (i == selectedPeople.Count)
            {
                sb.Append("and ");
            }
        }
        sb.Append(selectedPeople[i]);
    }
}


...

confirmation.Text = r + " has been booked on " + d + " by " + n + " for " + en + ". " + sb.ToString() + " will be attending.";
```

I would suggest you look into the other answer which suggests using SelectedItems though, to prevent having to do the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedPeople = list.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(c => c.Selected).Select(c => c.Text).ToList();
string people;
if (selectedPeople.Count == 1)
    people = selectedPeople[0];
else
    people = string.Join(", ", selectedPeople.Take(selectedPeople.Count - 1)) 
                + " and " + selectedPeople[selectedPeople.Count - 1];
```