# Writing max array value to console window

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, console-application

I am sure there is something stupid i am missing. I want to print the message
to console window and in the same line show the max array value.

When i run the code without the console message it runs perfect but when i run 
the code with the message, it only shows the message and no max value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] newArray = new int[6];

            newArray[0] = 0;
            newArray[1] = 1;
            newArray[2] = 2;
            newArray[3] = 49;
            newArray[4] = 3;
            newArray[5] = 82;

            Console.Write("The highest number in the array is: ",  newArray.Max());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am just starting to get the hang of arrays but i cannot find a solution to the above problem.

Comment: Console.Write("The highest number in the array is: {0} ",  newArray.Max());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
Console.Write("The highest number in the array is: {0} ", newArray.Max());
```

You can read more about string.format here: [Why use String.Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671610/why-use-string-format)

And here [Getting Started With String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting)

Comment: Thanks, i cant believe i forgot something so simple.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to concatenate the string:

```
Console.Write("The highest number in the array is: " + newArray.Max());
```

Another way is through a composite format string and a parameter:

```
Console.Write("The highest number in the array is: {0} ", newArray.Max());
```

Lastly, if you have Visual Studio 2015, you can do string interpolation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The highest number in the array is:{newArray.Max()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use new C# 6.0 feature called [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

```
Console.Write($"The highest number in the array is: {newArray.Max()}");
```