# what is different between these to ways in writeline()?

Tags: c#, .net, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# String output: format or concat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/c-sharp-string-output-format-or-concat)

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi there, {0} {1}!", userName, userSurname);
```

---

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi there, " + userName + " " + userSurname + "!" );
```

i wanna know what is different between these to ways and which is better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general **String.Format vs String concatenation** subject has been discussed number of times on StackOverflow, please refer to following questions (just to start with):

- [When is it better to use String.Format vs string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296978/when-is-it-better-to-use-string-format-vs-string-concatenation)
- [C# String output: format or concat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/c-sharp-string-output-format-or-concat)
- [Why use String.Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671610/why-use-string-format)
- [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c)
- [c# string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019508/c-sharp-string-formatting)

Comment: Wouldn't close as duplicate be more appropriate then?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen The question is as a duplicate of which one exactly. All above questions bring something new to the subject and none of them has been closed as a duplicate (despite the fact that there was suggestions in every one of them).

Answer (score 3):

**For:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi there, {0} {1}!", userName, userSurname);
```

Your first call resolves to: `Console.WriteLine(string,object,object)`

IN IL

```
 IL_000d:  ldstr      "Hi there, {0} {1}!"
 IL_0012:  ldloc.0
 IL_0013:  ldloc.1
 IL_0014:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string,
                                                                object,
                                                                object)
```

**For:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi there, " + userName + " " + userSurname + "!" );
```

While your second statement makes a call to `string.Concat` method.

```
IL_0042:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string[])
IL_0047:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

If you look at the code using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), you will see that the part where you have used `+` for string concatenation is replaced with call to `string.Concat` method

```
string userName = "Test";
string userSurname = "Test2";
Console.WriteLine("Hi there, {0} {1}!", userName, userSurname);
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(new string[]
{
    "Hi there, ",
    userName,
    " ",
    userSurname,
    "!"
}));
```

With respect to difference in performance, I believe if there is any its going to be negligible.

Comment: Basically, this IL does two API calls to mscorlib. It stays very close to the language. Although the idea of getting IL code for this question is great and deserves its upvotes, I feel disappointed by the results.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same.

At runtime, first option is resolved to create complete string.

Still First is better as its a much cleaner way of judging what string will look like finally.

Answer (score 1):

The first one involves the standard .NET formatting, the second one is a simple string concatenation.

I prefer the first one, because **it keeps display separated from the data**, and it allows me to store differents format string to do localization, for example. Here is the idea :

```
var EnglishFormat = "Hi there, {0} {1}!";
var FrenchFormat = "Salut tout le monde, {0} {1}!";
...

Console.WriteLine(currentLocaleFormat, userName, userSurname);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the result.

The first one uses string formatting the second one concatenates the strings.

Try to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c) concatenations because it uses more memory

Answer (score 0):

Both of the examples will print the same result.
I find that it's much more easy to see what the result should be in the first example, if the string that should be showed is long one then it could be hard to see how it will look like.

I'm always using the first example when i should print something to the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two commands both output the same result.First one is better because it avoids extra empty strings concatinations.