# Populating a ListBox with List<Entity>

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using LINQ to Entites in my WindowsForm application.

I am trying to populate a Lisbox with the result of a query:

So my datasource is a List where User is a table in my database and a EntityType in my model.

The problem is I want the Displaymember to bea concat of 3 different Columns. (User.Firstname + " " + user.LastName + " - " + user.userCode)

and ValueMember to be user.ID;

I could just create a struct of a userItem with the 4 items, iterate through the list of User's and add them to another List. But this seems like double processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the Entity in the partial class with a custom property like this:

```
public partial class User
{
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
             return string.Format("{0} {1} - {2}", FirstName, LastName, UserCode);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add the property you can also use a Linq Projection to create a custom list with the computed property:

```
var listdata = (from u in Users
                select new
                {
                   Description = string.Format("{0} {1} - {2}", u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.UserCode).
                   Id = u.Id;    
                }.ToList();
```

Then you can bind listdata to your listbox.

Comment: I ended up extending my entity as you suggested. is String.format more efficent than just " " + " " + - "" ? or you just prefer it for cosmetic reasons

Comment: I always thought that string.Format was more efficient, that's why I used it in this example but when I searched for a reference I came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/c-sharp-string-output-format-or-concat and it appears that concatenation is faster!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a `property` in your `model` which returns the concatenated value from three `columns/properties`. Then set the `DisplayMemeber` equal to that property

Another way could be to add a [Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) in your table. Combine the value of rest of the columns through expression

Comment: I would shoot anyone who added a computed column to the database for what is essentially a display property. Just saying. Not a good place to put it.

Comment: I wouldnt put it on hte Database, but perhapes in the LINQ model it is acceptable?