# C# - Multiple strings on the same line in Messagebox

Tags: c#, variables, messagebox

I've recently started learning C#.
I have an `string` type of variable `a`.

I'm trying to get a `Messagebox` to show my variable and some text after it.

`MessageBox.Show(a "was your answer");` This doesn't work.
`MessageBox.Show(a, "was your answer");` While this throws the text to the title.

How could I make some text appear after the variable, on the same line?

Comment: it is called concatenation!

Comment: concatenate the string using + operator and place into your messagebox. you can create another variable to store that string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
MessageBox.Show(a + "was your answer");
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} was your answer", a));
```

Using

```
string.Format()
```

can be neater for multiple string variables and easier to change the string literal if you need to. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/string-output-format-or-concat-in-c) for a discussion on its use.

Your

```
MessageBox.Show(a, "was your answer");
```

throws the text to the title because the method signature of `MessageBox.Show()` that takes two arguments is for:

```
public static DialogResult Show(
    string text,
    string caption
)
```

> Displays a message box with specified text and caption.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need [concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

```
MessageBox.Show(a + "was your answer");
```

Comment: Well that was simple.

Comment: @Claudio Yes. Also see the 2nd method in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372927/c-sharp-multiple-strings-on-the-same-line-in-messagebox/22372937#22372937).