# In C# how do you use placeholders in Console.WriteLine()?

Tags: c#

Am I using the `{0}` and `{1}` correctly in the code below for the name variable and age variable? What are the `{0}` and `{1}` called, are they formally called "placeholders"? Is it more preferable to use the + concatenation or the placeholder system to incorporate variables into `Console.Writeline()`?

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi " + nameInput + ", you are " + ageInteger + " years old.");
Console.WriteLine("Hi {0}, you are {1} years old.", nameInput, ageInteger);
```

full code:

```
string nameInput;
string ageInputString;
int ageInteger;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
nameInput = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter your age");
ageInputString = Console.ReadLine();
Int32.TryParse(ageInputString, out ageInteger);
Console.WriteLine("Hi " + nameInput + ", you are " + ageInteger + " years old.");
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The option #2 (the second line in the first block) would be the best practice.

Answer (score 11):

With C# 6, you can now use the hybrid solution:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hi {nameInput} you are {ageInteger} years old.");
```

This is referred to as [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), this approach should be preferred because: _String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings than a string composite formatting feature_.

Comment: Also something to keep in mind is [Always use placeholders and avoid string interpolation](https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are called placeholders. Again, doesn't it look more readable when you say like below instead of concatenation

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} you are  {1} years old.", nameInput, ageInteger);
```

Answer (score 0):

{0} and {1} are called placeholders or format items.

As for the second question check [String output: format or concat in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/string-output-format-or-concat-in-c)