# Concat two strings when initialising class object without providing the concatenated string

Tags: c#, .net, string

How can i initialise the FullName variable to auto concat the previous two strings?

Due to system design and constraints I can't pass the concatenated string when initialising, so is there a way to initialise the FullName variable without providing the concat string initially?

```
    public class Person
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String SecondName { get; set; }

        //this should be first and second name together
        public String FullName{ get; set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FullName is not a real property and should have only a getter

```
public String FullName
{
   get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
}
```

and this is NOT java.. you can use **string**

### UPDATE

please stop concating string and start formatting them or building them with StringBuilder.. 
[String output: format or concat in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/string-output-format-or-concat-in-c)

Comment: In this circumstance what's wrong with doing a simple string concatenation?

Comment: in ANY circumstance it is wrong to use it - you are actually messing up your memory for nothing and spending computing resources with no good reason... it is a bad habit that developers use for some reason over and over again

Comment: @ymz - Don't forget to do an `@` notification - it was just luck that I kept this page open. Nonetheless, string concatenation **doesn't** mess up memory - The garbage collector is perfectly able to clean up after small objects nicely. Computing resources are cheap these days and the resources required to clean up a single concatenation is almost infinitesimally negligible. Besides, the source for `String.Format` almost immediately goes and calls `Format(null, format, new Object[] {arg0, arg1})` which has created some garbage to be collected. It then goes on to create a `StringBuilder`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String SecondName { get; set; }

    //this should be first and second name together
    public String FullName{ get { return FirstName + " " + SecondName; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VS with me right now so syntax may be slightly off, but:

```
public String FullName{ get { return FirstName + " " + SecondName; }
```

Should do it - not there is no setter anymore since `FullName`s value is derived from `FirstName` and `SecondName`.

Answer (score 0):

it is a little bit faster:

```
public String FullName{ get { return String.Concat(FirstName, " ", SecondName); }}
```

But **String.Format(...)** is clear and easy to modify.