# Why use a placeholder?

Tags: c#, methods, placeholder

I have a mini project im working on in c#. I'm fairly new to c# and was wondering why I should use a placeholder {0} instead of a +. Are there any differences? Any benefit to using one over the other?

Heres an example-

```
 public void DisplayMessage()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Student Name:"+ Name); // Why not this
    Console.WriteLine("Studnt Age: {0}", Age);// instead of this?
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: I see that you aren't trying to micro-optimize and are simply curious. [Here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) is something you'll like.

Comment: In C#6 you could also add `Console.WriteLine($"Student Age: {Age}");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String output: format or concat in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/string-output-format-or-concat-in-c)

Comment: Complex formatting, multiple fields and tweaking is much easier with string format

Comment: @displayName  ok so what I got from that is that it really doesnt matter?

Answer (score 2):

Formatted string is clearer than adding strings, especially when you have more than two parameters.

```
static readonly string UrlFormat = "{0}://{1}/{2}?{3}";  //the format can be reused
var url = string.Format(UrlFormat, scheme, host, path, query);
var anotherUrl = string.Format(UrlFormat, scheme2, host2, path2, query2);
var bad = scheme3 + "://" + host3 + "/" + path3 + "?" + query3;
```

By the way in C#6 the format can be more pretty:

```
var urlUsingNewFeature = $"{scheme}://{host}/{path}?{query}";
```

You can see the maintenance cost between them.

**The performance** The only advantage of adding strings is that when you adding two strings, it's faster than string formatting.

```
"Student Name: " + name
```

is a little faster than

```
string.Format("Student Name: {0}", name)
```

I did the benchmark before, adding <=3 strings is faster than using `string.Format`. But IMO you still should use `string.Format`, the tiny performance improvement is not that important.

Comment: Yeah the end user wont notice a difference anyway..

Comment: @user3793369 But as a backend developer, we should care about those won't be seen by users. Code style and re-usage is quite important.

Comment: @user3793369 Maybe, but still you better stick to the best practices

Comment: @user3793369 As a developer staring at that line of code at 10pm following a bad deployment and lots of emergency meetings and triage. I can tell you that the difference is night and day. That is either leaving work during night, or day.